# C++ shared_ptr array type access

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I'm making a wrapper for a SQL database and the objects I return are `shared_ptr`.
I'd like to support array-type access (ie `row["column"]` instead of `row->get("column")`). The objects the `shared_ptr` stores support array-type access, but of course the `shared_ptr` doesn't.
How should I do this with `shared_ptrs`, would I need to extend the class?

Comment: @BoBTFish: I seem to remember that operator[] must be a meber...

Comment: Correct, I just stuck that there as a first thought. Now I tested it and realised it didn't work, I've deleted the suggestion.

Comment: @IgorR. I guess that will be the easiest way, but I was hoping to avoid the indirection. Oh well.

Comment: @user1520427 besides the technical issues, I don't believe it would be a good idea. Afterall, shared_ptr is a *pointer* and this fact should be clear to those who read your code. (By the way, note that there is shared_array as well.)

Comment: Good point, I might just save myself some hassle and use indirection. Thanks.

Comment: @IgorR. That should be an answer. It is simple and expresses the intent clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious thing is to add an `operator[]` to `shared_ptr`.
That means define your-own shared_ptr reusing std::shared_ptr and having the [] operator working the way you want.

This can be done in a quick and dirty way by deriving shared_ptr (note: shared_ptr are not polymorphic objects, so don't mix up std:: and yours in a same context, so that you can reuse their interface).

If you are a "don't derive if the destructor isn't virtual" fan, than it is up to you to embed std::shared_ptr in `yourptr`, and rewrite the shared_ptr interface in `yourptr` one, delegating the functionality you have to retain.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid rewriting the interface, but seeing as its destructor function isn't virtual I guess I don't have much choice. Out of curiosity, do you know why the std lib functions aren't virtual? Is it a performance thing?

Comment: Because they are not be intended for "polymorphism". The problem is that OOP fans think that derivationm is for OOP only. But to that's their fault, not of who derives.   See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10478845/924727 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/11202368/924727